# Text aligned to the left and right of a div to move to separate lines both on the left side of the div?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way with HTML and CSS to make text that floats to the left and right side of a div that will also overflow onto a new line where the right-aligned text stays to the left when it's on the new line? What I am talking about is depicted below where the gray is the div.

[image]

If the div is shrunken further, each text should wrap on its own, so it would look like this:

> Left Text
>   Right
>   Text

and eventually...

> Left
>   Text
>   Right
>   Text

All text should be on the left side if they touch; otherwise they should be on the same line left and right.

Comment: You can use media query if this is width related issue.

Comment: I know, but then I would have to know an exact total width of the text so I was wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: You can't do it if there is no fix value. You should use javascript or jquery to achieve this since we need to adjust the css depending on the `width` values. Unless someone smarter will comment here and prove me wrong then please ignore this comment ;)

Comment: I see your solution requires it too, although it's much cleaner than media queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gtBBZ/1/)**

html

```
<div class="a">
<div class="c" style="float:left;">Left Text</div>
<div class="c" style="float:right;">Right Text</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
<div class="b">
<div class="c" style="float:left;">Left Text</div>
<div class="c" style="float:right;">Right Text</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.a {
    width:200px;
    border:solid 1px #ccc;
}
.b {
    width:100px;
    border:solid 1px #ccc;
}
.c {
    width:100%;
    max-width:100px;
}
```

Setting a max-width for `.c` to half of the width of `.a` will help

**BUT** this requires fix values for the width. It would be better to use javascript or jquery here to adjust the css according to the `width` values

Comment: Nice answer but I'll wait until tomorrow accept your answer to see if anyone else knows how without JS to find the width. +1 for now.

Answer (score 0):

Not certain I understand what you're saying, but I think MAYBE this is what you want:

```
<p class="left-text">This is some words</p>
<p class="right-text">This is some other words that wrap because there are too many in here. Holy crap this is a lot of words!!</p>
```

CSS:

```
.left-text {
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
  float: left;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7pGcy/2/)

Maybe you want to make the left text occupy half the parent instead of just setting a margin spacer?

```
display: inline-block;
width: 50%;
margin: 0;
float: left;
```

[Fiddle#2](http://jsfiddle.net/7pGcy/3/)

EDIT: ok. Here you go then.

```
.left-text {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}

.right-text {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
}
```

[Fiddle3](http://jsfiddle.net/7pGcy/10/)

Comment: Answer #1: The entire block needs to drop to the next line if it runs out of space. Answer #2: That may come in handy, but still not what I'm looking for.

Comment: You'll have to clarify. It's doing exactly what your image above appears to need. Do you mean, the text is justified right and you want it left instead? You can add text-align left to the 'right-text' to fix that.

Comment: When the block of text is on the same line, Left Text should be on the left and Right Text should be on the right. When there's not enough space because the div is smaller, BOTH text blocks should be on the left.

Comment: Oh, got it. You're saying, if the right-text runs into the left text, but doesn't have enough text to wrap to a second line on it's own, then it's still rests on the right margin. I think you're going to have to need to use JS, since neither of the widths are a known value (if one of them was known, you could use media-queries).

Comment: Ok. One last idea: is it possible to use a media query to check the height of a container div to essentially check if it has moved to the next line?

Comment: #3 above, if the right text is long enough to wrap on it's own, then both of them will sit on the left edge. It's only if the width is between "too big to fit on same line as left" and "still smaller than parent container".

Comment: If the they run into each other, they should both be moved to a new line without any text running from the previous line. If it gets even shorter, then they should both move to their own new lines separately. Basically they should never be on the same line except when they both fit.

Comment: My mistake, you're not going to be able to use media-queries in this way. You're going to need to use JS here.

Comment: I see. Thanks for trying, and settling it on JS so I don't keep looking for a CSS solution.

Answer (score 0):

Say this is the code for your div:

```
<div>

Text on left

Text on right

</div>
```

You could give these their on tag like this:

```
<div>

<left>
Text on left
</left>

<right>
Text on right
</right>

</div>
```

Then finally, you could add in the css:

```
<style>
left {
float: left;
}
right {
float: right;
}
</style>
```

I know I'm late to the party, but I hope this helps!